# Uppercase Snake Case Application Settings in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We're doing an exercise involving applying application settings in Azure at the point of release. We're trying to categorise different types of settings and keep coming across the uppercase, snake case application settings in Azure. For example:

WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE

I've looked online but failed to find a common naming group for these type of application settings. What's the official naming for these types of settings?

Comment: In the context of Azure, these settings are typically referred to as "Azure environment variables" or "Azure application settings."

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that, it's just that within the regular Azure environment variables or Azure application settings, there is this specific subset of variables that are all in uppercase with underscores.  Is there a word or words for describing these types?

Comment: Azure that are in uppercase with underscores is often referred to as "reserved" or "well-known" application settings.

These settings are pre-defined and have specific meanings in the context of Azure Web Apps or other Azure services that support application settings. They are used to control various aspects of the app's behavior, configuration, or runtime environment.

Comment: Here are some examples of commonly used reserved application settings in Azure:

WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE: Specifies the default time zone for the web app.
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: Used for deployment scenarios when you want to run the app from a package.
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION: Sets the default Node.js version for the app.

Comment: Perfect, I like both of those terms and they'll work well for describing them in this current task.  Do you want to supply that as an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this an answer as discussed in comment:

In the context of Azure, these settings are typically referred to as "Azure environment variables" or "Azure application settings."

Azure that are in uppercase with underscores is often referred to as "reserved" or "well-known" application settings.

These settings are pre-defined and have specific meanings in the context of Azure Web Apps or other Azure services that support application settings. They are used to control various aspects of the app's behavior, configuration, or runtime environment.

Here are some examples of commonly used reserved application settings in Azure:

1. WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE: Specifies the default time zone for the web app.
2. WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: Used for deployment scenarios when you want to run the app from a package.
3. WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION: Sets the default Node.js version for the app.